# HTML/JS detection of Windows 8.1 pinned site

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8.1, pinned-site

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg491733(v=vs.85).aspx is a page from the launch of IE9 with the ability to pin sites to the Windows 7 taskbar. It appears that in IE11 (Windows 8.1) the listed property continues to only reflect whether a site has been launched from a TASKBAR-PINNED site, and does not have anything to do with the new Windows 8/8.1 start screen pinning.

Since I have a dynamic live tile for the site, I would like to encourage Windows 8.1 users to pin my site to keep up-to-date on the latest posts. But I don't want to encourage non-Windows 8.1 users to do so, obviously. Ideally, I'd even rather not show anything like that to an 8.1 user who has already pinned the site, as it would be redundant!

So, does anyone know if there is a similar JS function which IE11 can use to detect on whether the user can and has pinned the site to the start screen?

Thanks!